# Браузер неправильно отображает height

Tags: html, css

Дал всем псевдоклассам и `span` `height: 2px;`
но почему то браузер отображает `span` толще чем псевдоклассы. Как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.header__burger {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.header__burger span::before {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
}

.header__burger span::after {
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -10px;
}

.header__burger span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__burger">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Запускаю твой пример в Опере - вроде все полосочки одинаковой высоты... У тебя в каком браузере такая картинка?

Comment: использую всегда хром

Comment: Обновил свой Хром до последней версии - все полоски одинаковые...

Comment: Спасибо, значит только у меня что то с браузером

Comment: Т.е. ты тут запускаешь и полоски разные?

Comment: Да тут тоже когда запускаю

Comment: Браузер обновил, проблема осталась

Comment: А если поиграться с масштабированием страницы в браузере (увеличить/уменьшить), визуальная толщина линий Вашего бургера меняется? Я ловил подобную неприятность, когда при фактической идентичности толщин линий, браузер почему-то решил одну из них отобразить чуть толще. Точно не помню, но, кажется, при увеличении масштаба страницы, проблема уходила. Похоже, что это просто глюк конкретного браузера на конкретной ОС. По сути решения проблемы я так и не смог найти, но она со временем решилась сама собой)

Comment: Масштабирование тоже не помогло, интересно то что когда двигаешь элемент при помощи top то бывает становится нормальной толщиной

Comment: Попробуйте иконки использовать в `svg` формате, чтобы они не ломались при масштабировании и выглядели везде одинаково. Они легко поддаются для анимирования и проблем с `UI` составляющей не возникнет.

Answer (score 2):

Почти наверняка потому что они субпиксельные.

1. Если высота блока нечётная, то средняя полоса должна встать между пикселями, а значит она будет отображена иначе.
2. Если используется масштабирование экрана (на ноутах часто 125% или 150%), то даже при чётной высоте виртуальные пиксели не наложатся ровно на физические и отображение поедет. Используй реальный экранный пиксель чтобы это исправить:

   ```
   html
     --spx: 1px;
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:  .09)   { --spx: 10px;          }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:  .25)   { --spx: 4px;           }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:  .33)   { --spx: 3px;           }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:  .5 )   { --spx: 2px;           }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:  .66)   { --spx: 1.5px;         }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:  .75)   { --spx: 1.333333333px; }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:  .79)   { --spx: 1.25px;        }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:  .89)   { --spx: 1.111111111px; }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1   )   { --spx: 1px;           }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25)   { --spx: .8px;          }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5 )   { --spx: 0.666666666px; }
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.75)   { --spx: 0.571428571px; }
     /* А тут пусть будет нормальный */
     @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2   )   { --spx: 1px; }
   ```

Comment: Да, скорее всего проблема в масштабировании. Попробовал в хроме - если масштаб 125%, то крайние полоски толще средней, а если 175% - наоборот.